# Drum transition stuck when key pressed down for a prolonged time

Tags: css-transitions

Im still relatively new to coding but i followed a tutorial for a drumset and then made my own which can be shown here: https://jonathanbeuzelin.github.io/mydrumset/index.html

When a key is held down for a prolonged amount of time the transition will stick and will not return back to its normal state.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
function playSound(e) {
  const audio = document.querySelector(`audio[data-key="${e.keyCode}"]`);
  const key = document.querySelector(`.key[data-key="${e.keyCode}"]`);

  if (!audio) return; // stop the function from running all together
  audio.currentTime = 0; // this will rewind it to the start
  audio.play();
  console.log(key);
  key.classList.add('playing');
}

function removeTransition(e){
  if(e.propertyName !== 'transform') return; // skip it if its not a transform
  this.classList.remove("playing")
}

const keys = document.querySelectorAll('.key');
keys.forEach(key => key.addEventListener('transitionend', removeTransition));
window.addEventListener('keydown',playSound);
</script>
```

Comment: Example is no longer working.